# how can i keep my data alive on mysql workbench?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

i'm connecting  with mysql workbench using usearname root  with nodejs  and  sequelize , my data  disepears after  a while of time , i already  edited the preferences and changed DBMS to 86400 and  still the same problem , i want to keep  my data  always  not just  for  24 hours , here my code of connection with sequelize and a  screenshot of mysqlk workbench .

```
const Sequelize=require('sequelize')


const sequelize =new Sequelize(
 process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
 process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
 process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
     dialect:"mysql",
     host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
     port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
     operatorAliases:false,
       logging:false,
       options: {
           requestTimeout: 60000,
         },
       
       pol:{
         idle: 30000,
         min: 1,
         // max: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_MAX_POOL),
         acquire: 60000,
       }
   }

)

sequelize
 .sync({force:true })
 .then(() => {
   console.log("Connection with dataBase " + process.env.DATABASE_NAME + " has been established!")
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log(err)
 })

module.exports = sequelize
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the force flag inside sync.
If sequelize models find changes with the current db_stucture sequelize will drop the database and change the schema of it.

That is the reason that in production we never use that flag.
If someone wants to change the structure while keeping the data, he should use migrations which change the database while implementing logic to keep or change his data accordingly.

Comment: thank you  for the  answer ,   can u tell how can  i  add migration ?

Comment: You can start here. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html.

Comment: thank you  o already solder the  problem but deleting  force:true